# Separate hosting for SPA and Website but share domain

Tags: firebase, dns, single-page-application, firebase-hosting, webflow

I want to separate hosting of my **app** and **website**. The hierarchy is as follows:

- `example.com` - website hosted at DigitalOcean
- `example.com/*` - SPA hosted at Firebase Hosting

Since DNS does not allow to point the subdirectories, is there any wiser way, to accomplish this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you thought about using a subdomain for either your website or app? I think this would be the cleanest solution: app.example.com pointing to firebase, example.com to DO (or the other way around)

Comment: Hi @Scarysize, thanks reaching out. We currently want to keep it flat, without a subdomain. Good example is Marvel – they have marvelapp.com as website and subdirectories for the app itself (marvelapp.com/projects etc.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the subdomain solution isn't favored, you could try a proxy like nginx to route traffic based on the path to different backends. An example configuration might look something like this:

```
server {
    listen       ...;
    ...
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://<your-website>;
    }

    location /app {
        proxy_pass http://<your-app>;
    }

    location /another-app {
        proxy_pass http://<another-app>;
    }
    ...
}
```

Source: https://gist.github.com/soheilhy/8b94347ff8336d971ad0

You may also want to check whether the Digital Ocean load balancer product offers path based routing.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'm marking it as solved. Please check my solution below for a savvy approach ;)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving the problem via subdomains and decided to share this workaround.

**1. DNS records as follows**

```
www : pointing to website
* : root pointing SPA
```

**2. In my Vue app I just added a simple `window.replace` to redirect from root to `www`.**

```
if (window.location.host === 'example.com') window.location.replace('https://www.example.com');
```

--

Far from neat, but works just fine :)

---

***I'm marking @Scarysize's answer as the solving one, since it's a more comprehensive solution.***